# Is ripple-keypairs package deprecated ? it's not working for me

Tags: react-native, npm, ripple, wallet

i want to create a wallet using 'ripple-keypairs' package, i have done the exact code as in npm but there are numerous errors,i tried numerous methods with the help of AI and docs , if anyone has the code for react-native for ripple wallet creation, please help out